# Setting dropdown option from Javascript based on querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I have a partial view which has a dropdown in it and I include that partial in my page twice.  Here is the dropdown.

```
<form name="sortbyformtop">
            <select onchange="sort('@querystring', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" name="sortbyselecttop">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="accommodationtype">Accommodation type</option>
                <option value="mostreviewed">Most reviewed</option>
                <option value="lowestprice">Lowest price</option>
            </select>
        </form>
```

Now, when the page loads, if the querystring contains a key `sortby` then I would like to take the value of `sortby` (which will be `accommodationtype`, `mostreviewed`, `lowestprice` i.e. the value of the options).  What I'd like to do is set both dropdowns on the page to the option that matches the `sortby` query string value.  I've tried lots of things but nothing is working.

Can you help?

**Edit**

I tried this but it did not work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#sortbyselecttop option").filter(function () {
                    alert($(this).text());
                    return $(this).text() == "lowestprice";
                }).first().prop("selected", true);
            });
```

Comment: Can you post some examples of what you've tried?

Comment: Thanks. First problem I can see is that your jQuery selector `$('#sortbyselecttop option')` is looking for an `id` of 'sortbyselecttop', whereas you've given it a `name` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I've read it well, but do you simply want the dropdown to select the value of the query string ?

If so, try this :

```
$('select[name="sortbyselecttop"]').val('accommodationtype');
```

It would be better if the select had a class name so you could set both dropdowns with one jQuery command.

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QEv4C/)

Comment: I put this in a <script type="text/javascript"> tag but that didn't work.

Comment: make sure it's in a $(document).ready() statement. Also. I had an error previously. I was missing the ]. Could you try again

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { $('select[name="sortbyselecttop"]').val('accommodationtype');
 } )

Comment: I used your fiddle example.  I have given the dropdown a class and it works BUT only for the first one not the second one.  I have not put it in a document.ready function.

Comment: Did you give the class to the second dropdown also?

Comment: yep because the dropdown is in a partial and the partial is included twice in the page.

Comment: Ok. Then I would suggest you put it in a $(document).ready statement. Is the javascript also in the partial? or in a general .js file?

Comment: Note: If the javascript is in the partial, it will get executed twice. Not ideal, but not a big deal either. Just letting you know!

Answer (score 1):

you can not access a control with name like `$("#name")` this is a selector to select a DOM with ID only. but still you can set value of the dropdown like

```
$("select [name='sortbyselectop']").val(value);
```

assuming value is the variable in which your query string value is

```
function Querystring(qs)
{
this.params = {};
this.get = Querystring_get;
this.args = {};
qs = qs ? qs.replace(/^#/g, '') : location.search.substring(1, location.search.length);

if (qs.length == 0)
    return;
qs = qs.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
this.args = qs.split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < this.args.length; i++)
{
    var pair = this.args[i].split('=');
    var name = unescape(pair[0]);

    var value = (pair.length == 2)
     ? unescape(pair[1])
     : name;

    this.params[name] = value;
}
this.joined = function()
{
    var join = new Array();
    for (var a in this.params)
    {
        join.push(a + '=' + this.params[a]);
    };
    return join.join('&');
};

}
function Querystring_get(key, defaultValue)
{
var value = this.params[key];
return (value != null) ? value : defaultValue;
};
```

try these functions and get value like

```
var qs = new Querystring().get("sortby", '');
```

now qs will have your query string value and you can set value of the drop down like

```
$("select [name='sortbyselectop']").val(qs);
```

hope this will work.